# Using "Buffer Without Overlaps" plugin (QGIS)

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins

I am trying to use the "[Buffer Without Overlaps](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/buffer_without_overlaps/)" plugin with [this shape file](https://tmpfiles.org/dl/1140041/aa.zip).

However, I am facing the following issue:

> Error: Algorithm saga:polygonselfintersection not found

[image: Error message]

How do I proceed?

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works

Comment: is saga installed?

Comment: @IanTurton, saga is installed. However, Saga Next Generation was installed in my case. Thus, I had to change the algorithm ID from "saga:polygonselfintersection" to "sagang:polygonselfintersection" in the Python code. Now, it worked.

Comment: please add that as the answer to your question for others who may have the same issue