# Editing Python code of QGIS plugin

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-plugins

I would like to edit the python code of this plugin : "Buffer Without Overlaps " https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/buffer_without_overlaps/ as it's mentioned in the answer wrote by @bbublue [Using "Buffer Without Overlaps" plugin (QGIS)](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/455890/using-buffer-without-overlaps-plugin-qgis/460835#460835)

Comment: To start, see the official doc : https://docs.qgis.org/3.28/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/plugins/plugins.html#getting-started

Comment: If you want to edit it you can. If you've installed it, it will be in your plugins folder or you can download the source (linked to on the plugin page).  What is your specific question?

Comment: The easiest way to find the plugins folder mentioned by @user2856 is in QGIS click `Settings > User Profiles > Open Active Profile Folder` then navigate to `python > plugins` and you will find a folder there with the plugin name that contains the source code. Beware that any changes you make there will directly affect the plugin so you might end up breaking it. If so, you can re-install it to get the original code back.

Comment: Thank you for the answers.
I wanna to fix the bug message : "Algorithm saga:polygonselfintersection not found"